# windows echo to overwrite previous echo

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a batch file, I want to write a "counter" to the screen without scrolling stuff off the screen.  I have

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,1000) DO (
< NUL set /P="Count= %%i"
)
```

{There is no space between `< LT> NUL` but this stops the line from showing in the question.}

This command doesn't add a LF or CR, but I do want a CR, just no LF.

The end result should be

```
Count= X
```

where X is "counting" from 1 to 1,000.

Comment: I know this is possible, as I've seen   |  /  -  \  "cycled" through to look like a spinning wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a Carriage Return (Ascii 13) in CR variable:
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,1000) DO ( < NUL set /P "=Count= %%i!CR!" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set cnt=0
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"


FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,5) DO ( 
 call :cnt
 timeout /t 1 >nul
 < NUL set /P "=!er!!CR!"
 )
echo.
pause
exit 
:cnt
set /a cnt=!cnt!+1
if %cnt% == 1 set er=Hello!                             
if %cnt% == 2 set er=I am Soubhik Biswas                                 
if %cnt% == 3 set er=My Roll Is 40                          
if %cnt% == 4 set er=Is Study In Class VIII-C       
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made